# How java abstraction works in a real time project

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, abstraction

I went through many articles to understand the abstraction concept. Most of them have defined abstraction as hiding implementations from the code that uses the methods.

Example

```
public interface test1 {
    String doSomething();
}

public class test2 implements test1 {
    String doSomething() {
    }
}

public class test3 {
    void m1() {
        test1 t = new test2();
        t.doSomething();
    }
}
```

My question is that if the abstraction hides the implementation details, `test3` does not know about `doSomething()` method's implementation. But the developer should know about which classes have implemented this interface and purpose of these classes. Then what does "hiding implementation" exactly mean here?. Could anyone please explain this?

Comment: "Real time" does not mean "real world" or "real life"; it has a specific other meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As you talked about real life examples, no one know how hashCode() function for all classes in java api is implemented. but you know what is utility of that function.

The main point here is that someone who is using hashCode(), don't bother about its implementation details, compatible changes made over releases, he can just use it if it suits.

Also good explanations for this can be found on internet.

Comment: hashCode() is not abstract.

Comment: I am explaining concept not thekey

Comment: I am explaining concept of abstraction not the keyword

Comment: @Omid.N But `hashCode()` _is_ "virtual", and lots of classes override it.

Comment: @asvni But I disagree. Abstraction is an inheritance concept. It does not matter if you see the code or not. The word abstract means something that is "general". When you make a class abstract, you mean that this class is "raw", use its subclasses instead.

Answer (score 1):

Abstraction is not about *Hiding* implementation details, it is about the higher-level idea of how things will work.

For example, in your above example:

```java
public interface test1 {
    String doSomething();
}

public class test2 implements test1 {
    String doSomething() {
    }
}

public class test3 {
    void m1() {
        test1 t = new test2();
        t.doSomething();
    }
}
```

If some other class is dependendent on a test functionality, that class can have it in a constructor like: `DependentClass(test1 test)` an you can pass it as `DependentClass(new test2())` or `DependentClass(new test3())`. The internal implementation of `DependentClass` only able to see `doSomething()` method signature, it don't care about how it is implemented in either of the `test2` or `test3` classes. 
In the future, if there is some test4 implementation that will be available, it could be used without changing a word in the implementation of `DependentClass`.

1. By the way, you should follow Java naming conventions
2. When someone uses the term hiding, typically they are talking about restricting the access, i.e hiding from other parts of the program, not the developer. In that sense, you could say that the implementation of `doSomething()` is *hidden* from `DependentClass` (it could be using some methods private to implementing class, which are not accessible in `DependentClass`), but again, that is not the point of having abstraction.